# In F#, how to take an integer defined by an Enum and Match to the same name in a discriminated union?

Tags: enums, f#, discriminated-union

I'm stuck.

In F#, I have the following enum:

```
type PenEnum = 
        | InkPen        =0    
        | FreehandPen   =1    
        | CirclePen     =2
        | LinePen       =3
        | RectanglePen  =4
        | TextPen       =5             
        | PolyLine      =6
        | DiabeticPen   =7
        | SineWavePen   =8
        | DiamondPen    =9
        | AnnotationPen =10
        | FreeFormShapePen =11
        | MultiColoredPen  =12
        | XYAxisPen        =13
        | TBarPen          =14
        | FilledCirclePen  =15
        | ImagePen         =16
        | None             =17
```

The integers are then saved in a database from C# code.

Upon recall from the database, I need these integers to access specific members of a discriminated union on which I can perform a match and execute specific code for each pen.

```
type MyPen = 
    | InkPen        of Stroke     
    | FreehandPen   of Stroke    
    | CirclePen     of Stroke
    | LinePen       of Stroke
    | RectanglePen  of Stroke
    | TextPen       of Stroke    
    | PolyLine      of Stroke
    | DiabeticPen   of Stroke
    | SineWavePen   of Stroke
    | DiamondPen    of Stroke
    | AnnotationPen     of Stroke
    | FreeFormShapePen  of Stroke
    | MultiColoredPen   of Stroke
    | XYAxisPen         of Stroke   
    | TBarPen           of Stroke   
    | FilledCirclePen   of Stroke 
    | ImagePen          of Stroke
```

Question: How can I take an integer defined by the PenEnum and Match to the same name (i.e., InkPen to InkPen) of the discriminated union MyPen? (Please note: The PenEnum is used by C# Code).

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I would not recommend having two separate types in this way as this is creating redundancy that may cause various issues (e.g. one type getting out of sync with the other one). A better idea would be:

1. Either to have just `MyPen` alongside with a function that pattern matches on the pen and returns an `int` with the number to be used in the database.
2. Or use the enum directly in `MyPen` and have a type for pen with the type and stroke, i.e., `type MyPen = { Type : PenEnum; Stroke : Stroke }`

That said, what you asked about can be done using reflection:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let makePen enumId stroke = 
  let enumName = 
    [ for e in typeof<PenEnum>.GetEnumValues() -> e ]
    |> Seq.pick (fun e -> if unbox<int> e = enumId then Some(typeof<PenEnum>.GetEnumName(e)) else None )
  let unionCase = 
    FSharpType.GetUnionCases(typeof<MyPen>)
    |> Seq.find (fun c -> c.Name = enumName)
  FSharpValue.MakeUnion(unionCase, [| stroke |])

makePen 4 "#ff00ff"   // RectanglePen "#ff00ff"
```